# Consulta SQL compleja con multiples tablas

Tags: sql

Tengo una base de datos en SQL que contiene las siguientes tablas:

- PILOTO
- TORNEO
- TORNEO_PILOTO
- TORNEO_FECHA
- TORNEO_FECHA_PUNTO

Básicamente funciona así:
Se cargan pilotos y torneos en sus tablas, luego en cada torneo se pueden asociar pilotos y a su vez cada torneo puede tener una o varias fechas, en cada fecha al finalizar, se cargan los puntos de cada piloto.

Para ver los resultados armé la siguiente query:

```
select B.id_piloto, B.apellido + ' ' + B.nombre as 'Piloto', convert(varchar, C.fechainicio, 103) as 'Fecha', D.puntos
from TORNEO_PILOTO A
inner join PILOTO B
on A.id_piloto = B.id_piloto
inner join TORNEO_FECHA C
on A.id_torneo = C.id_torneo
inner join TORNEO_FECHA_PUNTO D
on D.id_torneo_fecha = C.id_torneo_fecha
and D.id_piloto = B.id_piloto
where 1 = 1 
and A.id_torneo = 6
and A.eliminado = 0
and B.eliminado = 0
and C.eliminado = 0
and D.eliminado = 0
order by id_piloto asc
```

[image: resultadossql]

El problema es que me gustaría ver los resultados de la siguiente manera: que figure en el título la fecha de torneo y debajo el puntaje.

Edité una imagen para mostrar el resultado que quiero ver, quiero que me devuelva esto por cada piloto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: eso se llama tabla pivotante.. para que base de datos?

Comment: Quería meter la query en una vista, despues levantarla y listo, pero sí, sino la otra es levantar esto y con alguna tabla pivotante js mostrar los datos que quiero.

Comment: No entendi tu comentario.. para que base de datos? y la mayoria de las bases de datos tienen una instruccion pivot para hacer esto (o si no, alguna forma de hacerlo)

Comment: No puedes meter la query en una vista porque las columnas pueden variar. Necesitas código dinámico o usar alguna herramienta/utilería en el front-end para mostrarlo. Mi consejo es que uses la segunda opción siempre que sea posible.

Comment: Pensé que existia alguna forma con una tabla temporal y algun full join recorriendo cada fecha, pero voy a hacerlo como decís, por código. Gracias!

Comment: ¿cuantas columnas de fechas vas a tener?

Comment: por lo general se cargan 4 por torneo, pero esto es dinámico, un torneo puede tener una fecha o diez por ejemplo.

Comment: Hiciste cuatro comentarios, y parece que te resignaste a hacerlo por código sin contestar la primer pregunta que te hicieron, siendo que [sí hay manera](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Nicolas se te pregunto de forma clara un par de cosas que no aclaraste. Agradeceria te comportaras con quienes tratan de ayudarte... nunca contestaste la pregunta basica que te hicimos, y es para que base de datos... porque sql es el lenguaje de las bases de datos..pero no sabemos con que motor estas trabajando...

Comment: Perdón interpreté mal tu pregunta, el motor donde trabajo es sql server, ahí pude resolverlo con una query que respondieron abajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que solicitas se llama Pivot Dinámico.

```
Create Table dbo.TORNEO_PILOTO (id_piloto int, id_torneo int, eliminado int)
Create Table dbo.PILOTO(id_piloto int, apellido varchar(100), nombre varchar(100), eliminado int)
Create Table dbo.TORNEO_FECHA(id_torneo int, fechainicio date, eliminado int, id_Torneo_Fecha int)
Create Table dbo.TORNEO_FECHA_PUNTO(id_torneo_fecha int, puntos decimal (4,2), id_piloto int, eliminado int);
GO
Insert into dbo.PILOTO (id_piloto, apellido, nombre, eliminado)
values
(11,'Gimenez','Roli',0),
(26,'Pugliese','Matias',0),
(28,'Cerrato','Alexis',0);
Insert into dbo.TORNEO_PILOTO(id_piloto, id_torneo, eliminado)
values
(11,6,0),
(26,6,0),
(28,6,0);
Insert into dbo.TORNEO_FECHA(id_torneo, eliminado,fechainicio, id_Torneo_Fecha)
values
(6,0,'20210124',1),
(6,0,'20210207',2),
(6,0,'20210228',3),
(6,0,'20210321',4);
Insert into dbo.TORNEO_FECHA_PUNTO(id_torneo_fecha, puntos, id_piloto, eliminado)
values
(1,25.00,11,0),
(2,20.00,11,0),
(3,28.00,11,0),
(4,0.00,11,0),
(1,0.00,26,0),
(2,0.00,26,0),
(3,28.00,26,0),
(4,8.00,26,0),
(1,0.00,28,0),
(2,0.00,28,0),
(3,28.00,28,0);
```

Este es el escenario que planteas, con los datos que muestras, (más o menos). Remarco el más o menos, porque como no has puesto, ni la estructura ni las inserciones, pero el resultado que da tú query es el mismo. Por tanto si hay que adaptarlo, serían cambios menores.

El pivot dinámico tiene complejidades. Y podríamos dividirlo en partes.

**Obtener las columnas**

La primera parte es como obtener los nombres de las columnas y enlazar estos en una variable, para poder realizar un pivot por ellos. Aquí hay varias soluciones posibles. Como no has indicado la versión de servidor en la cual trabajas, pues voy a exponer una, aunque luego, te dejaré un enlace más explicado a como puede hacer, y con otras opciones.

Lo que hacemos, es realizar una concatenación de todos los distintos valores, que tenga `dbo.torneo_fecha`  para esa columna al objeto de obtener un solo resultado, y con [For_xml](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) y [Stuff](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), los ponemos en una fila, y le quitamos el primer carácter.

```
SELECT STUFF(
(
SELECT
   ',' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(fechainicio))
 FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT fechainicio
    FROM  dbo.TORNEO_FECHA
   ) AS T
ORDER BY 
    FECHAINICIO
FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'');
```

> [2021-01-24],[2021-02-07],[2021-02-28],[2021-03-21]

Ese es el resultado obtenido, que es lo que vamos a utilizar en la query.

**Pivot sobre los datos**

En esta parte vamos a introducir la query en una variable tipo nvarchar, para realizar una ejecución dinámica. La misma la formamos por un Select * from ( y dentro la query que has planteado ). Esto se llamará `T, luego pivotamos los valores para las fechas, que están contenidas dentro de la variable que armamos antes con las fechas.

```
declare @columns nvarchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @columns=
 stuff(
(
select
   ',' + quotename(ltrim(fechainicio))
 from
   (select distinct convert(varchar, fechainicio, 103) AS fechainicio
    from  dbo.torneo_fecha 
   ) as t
order by 
    fechainicio
for xml path('')
),1,1,'');

SET @sql = N'
    SELECT * FROM
        (
            select B.id_piloto, CONCAT(B.apellido, '' '', B.nombre) as [Piloto], convert(varchar, C.fechainicio, 103) as [Fecha], D.puntos
                from TORNEO_PILOTO A
                inner join PILOTO B
                on A.id_piloto = B.id_piloto
                inner join TORNEO_FECHA C
                on A.id_torneo = C.id_torneo
                inner join TORNEO_FECHA_PUNTO D
                on D.id_torneo_fecha = C.id_torneo_fecha
                and D.id_piloto = B.id_piloto
                where 1 = 1 
                and A.id_torneo = 6
                and A.eliminado = 0
                and B.eliminado = 0
                and C.eliminado = 0
                and D.eliminado = 0
            ) AS T
            PIVOT
            (
            SUM(PUNTOS) FOR Fecha IN ('+@COLUMNS +N')
            ) AS P;';
    PRINT @SQL;
```

Al final la salida de mensajes muestra la siguiente consulta, que realmente es bastante menos de lo que hemos tipeado.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        select B.id_piloto, CONCAT(B.apellido, ' ', B.nombre) as [Piloto], convert(varchar, C.fechainicio, 103) as [Fecha], D.puntos
            from TORNEO_PILOTO A
            inner join PILOTO B
            on A.id_piloto = B.id_piloto
            inner join TORNEO_FECHA C
            on A.id_torneo = C.id_torneo
            inner join TORNEO_FECHA_PUNTO D
            on D.id_torneo_fecha = C.id_torneo_fecha
            and D.id_piloto = B.id_piloto
            where 1 = 1 
            and A.id_torneo = 6
            and A.eliminado = 0
            and B.eliminado = 0
            and C.eliminado = 0
            and D.eliminado = 0
        ) AS T
        PIVOT
        (
        SUM(PUNTOS) FOR Fecha IN ([07/02/2021],[21/03/2021],[24/01/2021],[28/02/2021])
        ) AS P;
```

La he puesto en formato código, porque se ve mucho mejor la sintaxis. Por tanto la consulta anterior, ha montado un pivot sobre la columna puntos, para cada Fecha in la lista de valores, que se prepararon en la variable `@columns`.

Pero el código único a ejecutar sería este:

```
declare @columns nvarchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @columns=
 stuff(
(
select
   ',' + quotename(ltrim(fechainicio))
 from
   (select distinct convert(varchar, fechainicio, 103) AS fechainicio
    from  dbo.torneo_fecha 
   ) as t
order by 
    fechainicio
for xml path('')
),1,1,'');

SET @sql = N'
    SELECT * FROM
        (
            select B.id_piloto, CONCAT(B.apellido, '' '', B.nombre) as [Piloto], convert(varchar, C.fechainicio, 103) as [Fecha], D.puntos
                from TORNEO_PILOTO A
                inner join PILOTO B
                on A.id_piloto = B.id_piloto
                inner join TORNEO_FECHA C
                on A.id_torneo = C.id_torneo
                inner join TORNEO_FECHA_PUNTO D
                on D.id_torneo_fecha = C.id_torneo_fecha
                and D.id_piloto = B.id_piloto
                where 1 = 1 
                and A.id_torneo = 6
                and A.eliminado = 0
                and B.eliminado = 0
                and C.eliminado = 0
                and D.eliminado = 0
            ) AS T
            PIVOT
            (
            SUM(PUNTOS) FOR Fecha IN ('+@COLUMNS +N')
            ) AS P;';

Exec sp_executeSql @Sql;
```

[image: Resultado]

Luego si quieres tratar, por ejemplo el `NULL` del `id_piloto` 28, lo podrías realizar en el `Select * FROM`, ya que corresponde al alias `p`. Podrías hacer `Select p.id_piloto as [id Piloto], p.Piloto as [Nombre Piloto], isNull(p.[21/03/2021],0) as [21/03/2021]`.

[Pivot dinámico](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/14/pivot-dinamico-como-hacerlo-y-entenderlo/)

Comment: muy buena respuesta.. pero todavia no sabemos con que motor de bases de datos trabaja.. y si su bsae de datos no acepta PIVOT?

Comment: La captura de pantalla de los resultados que ha mostrado, es de Sql Management Studio, por tanto yo diría que es Sql Server

Comment: yo no diria nada.. porque le preguntamos 4 veces que base de datos era, y nunca lo dijo.. si.. parecer parece.. pero si esta usando una version vieja que no tiene PIVOT? no critico tu respuesta (que es excelente).. digo, que tal vez, habia que esperar...

Comment: sobre todo, porque OP no esta siendo de lo mas cortes que digamos en los comentarios...

Comment: Perdón no pensé que se referian en las preguntas al motor, uso sql server, gracias, esta query me funcionó. solamente en el declare de columns tuve que agregar un where para indicar las fechas de un torneo específico y fechas no eliminadas. Muy buena explicación!